# Release the web camera after using CurrentImage[]

Tags: import, data-acquisition, hardware

`CurrentImage[]` will capture an image from the webcam.  It is even possible to create a live video in the notebook using

```
Dynamic@CurrentImage[]
```

After using this function even a single time, Mathematica will not switch off or release the webcam any more, making it impossible to use the webcam from other programs on some systems.

How can I switch off / release the webcam from Mathematica, without quitting Mathematica completely?

Comment: Note: this question has been split from here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2142/12

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To turn the camera off you could use the undocumented function `` IMAQ`StopCamera[] ``. Similarly `` IMAQ`StartCamera[] `` will turn it back on again.

Alternatively you can use the On/Off button on the control interface returned by `ImageCapture[]`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]