# Is it possible to use Mathematica to record sound and/or vision?

Tags: import, sound

I think the title says it all. I know about `ImageCapture` which seems to capture stills.

Can `ImageCapture` be made to capture a movie analogous to using say QuickTime player (and export to video format)?

Likewise, if a microphone is connected to your computer (e.g. something that can be used by QuickTime to record) can Mathematica record sound?

**Edit**

Because I was aware of `ImageCapture` prior to posting this question I did some searches looking for functions that may involve recording e.g.:

```
?*ecord*
```

But got no hits. It is frustrating to find that capturing an image gets its own intuitive function name whereas recording sound does not. But even more frustration that on my Mac I get this:

```
SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]
SystemDialogInput::unsupt: "The \!\(\"RecordSound\"\) dialog type is not currently supported on this platform. "
```

**Edit 2**

Thanks for the frame by frame type capture solutions posted below but I was hoping for a more direct (native) solution -- even if undocumented -- that would be analogous to me just controlling QuickTime from within Mma (which can be done).

As for recording sound, does anyone know why `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]`
 isn't supported on Macs and what potential methods exist for Mac?

thanks

Mike

**Edit 3**

In Version 9 `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]` works on Macs.

Comment: SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"] brings up a dialog to record sound. With a loop and `CurrentImage[]` you can probably record video. Is this satisfactory?

Comment: Whatever [you do](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2148/73), _don't_ do a `Dynamic@ImageCapture[]` :)

Comment: @CHM, I could resist and did it, but nothing exploded :/

Comment: @Rojo I'm using MMA 8.0.4 on OSX, and when I evaluated it my MMA froze. I had to force-quit it, because it constantly closed and reopened my iSight. It's not like something blows up, it's just inconvenient :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]` will bring up a dialog that let's you record sound.  It works both on Windows and Mac in v9, but only on Windows in earlier versions.  It doesn't work on Linux.

But what if you need to record sound without user interaction, and you want to avoid a modal dialog?  The right way is to use some external and documented tool (e.g. [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net)), but I happened to try to [dissect](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/12) the `"RecordSound"` dialog, and here are the results.  These may be Mac-specific.

On Mac, I believe some sort of initialisation may be needed, but I'm not entirely sure.  Evaluating

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[7, 0]]
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[8, 0]]
```

will probably do this.  This is the least clear point so far.  This may not be needed on Windows.

Now,

- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[5]] `` will list the available devices by number
- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[6, deviceNumber]] `` will list the available formats for the device
- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[1, deviceNumber, formatNumber]] `` will start recording.  It returns control immediately.
- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[2]] `` will stop recording and return the duration.
- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[3]] `` will return the recorded sound (it's the "OK" button in the dialog)
- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[4]] `` will *probably* discard the recorded sound (it's the Cancel button)
- `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[9, 0]] `` will return the current volume of the recorded sound, and is used for the progress indicator in the dialog.

**Warning:** This functionality is undocumented, and not meant for end users. I'm just guessing at how it works.  There's a real risk that playing with these will crash your front end, mess up its internal state or will cause a memory leak.  Use at own risk.

Answer (score 16):

```
vid[time_, frame_] := Module[{tag},
  Reap[Do[Sow[CurrentImage[], tag];
     Pause[frame], {Round[time/frame]}]][[2, 1]]]
```

So, `vid[1., 0.001]` would return a list of snapshots taken every 0.001 seconds over a second.

This opens a dialog that allows you to record sound and returns it as a `Sound` object

```
SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"];
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `CurrentImage` and set up a `ScheduledTask` to capture frames at the desired fps. Something like:

```
frames = {};
fps = 30;
task = CreateScheduledTask[frames = {CurrentImage[], frames};, 1/fps];
```

Then start and stop recording with

```
StartScheduledTask[task];
StopScheduledTask[task];
```

Note that stopping the task won't turn off the camera on a Mac (don't know about other systems). In order to turn it off, you'll have to execute `` IMAQ`StopCamera[] ``

Finally, to play the video back, run

```
ListAnimate[Reverse@Flatten@frames, fps]
```

---

Re: sound, `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"];` as Rojo pointed out is the way to go. However, this does not work on a mac and I'm not aware of an easy way to do it. You could perhaps interface with java to record sound, but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: I'm intrigued as to how much you can trust the scheduling to be done in time and not too off

Comment: @Rojo you need a RT operating system implementation to be sure that the frames are captured on time ... and none of them runs Mma.

Comment: @belisarius my intrigue is more statistic, practical than exact. I'm testing, for example, to run it for 2 seconds at 100fps and get a total of 131 frames recorded

Comment: My approach also fails. In the sense that it takes 3.5 seconds to record what should be 2 seconds of video at 100fps

Comment: @Rojo That's because of Mathematica's inherent slowness in accessing the hardware. Yours isn't accurate either — just a different kind of inaccuracy. On my machine, `vid[2., 1/100]; // AbsoluteTiming` takes 2.14 seconds :)

Comment: Yeah. In my machine it takes 3.5 seconds, hehe. And with your approach I can get more than 200 frames in 2 seconds if I ask for a much higher fps number. Perhaps doing some adjustment in the fps number used, or in my Pause, is quite important

Comment: @Rojo I believe my approach samples correctly... just that starting and stopping it are kind of hazy. I tested the video out and when played back at the correct fps, it runs smoothly. But you're right, `RunScheduledTask` is probably not what you'd want for precise timings. In the same vein, Mathematica is probably not the right tool for video capturing either =)

Comment: Really? I was starting to think that I was wrong and that it was way more suited (or less less suited than other MMA options) to these tasks since you don't have to account for the time it takes to save the data (as long as it doesn't take more than the time between events), and it's preemtive. Perhaps one could save a timestamp too to recognize skips and then patch it by inserting a duplicate frame or something

Comment: @Rojo Try with `task = CreateScheduledTask[Print@Last@Date[], 1]` and you'll see that there's a drift — possibly oscillating. It's about 0.02s in 20s on my machine, which is quite high.

Answer (score 4):

I used the answer above to create a small function to grab a bit of sound using the default microphone on my computer.

```
 Clear[recordTime];
recordTime[t_: 1] := 
 Module[{device = FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[5]]},
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[1, Keys[First[device]], 1]];
  Pause[t];
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[2]];
  FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[3]]]
```

This function could easily be extended to control which microphone (if multiple devices were present) and which format to use.

I am using a Mathematica 10 on Windows 8.

NOTE: I really wanted to upvote the answer that gave me the information I needed here, but i'm new and i don't have enough "reputation" to vote yet.

Comment: Regarding reputation: you do now.

Answer (score 2):

For a GUI experience, you can use `VideoCapture[]` and `AudioCapture[]`. If you want to have programmatic control to streams from your camera or microphone, You can look into `VideoRecord[]` and `AudioRecord[]`