# How can I import sound from within a Manipulate expression?

Tags: programming, manipulate, sound

I want to import sound from a file, record, and import sound.

```
Manipulate[{
  (*Audio Import Browse*)
  Audiopath1 = 
    FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "Audio.wav"}]}, 
  Column["Audio File (.wav) " 
    {Row[{InputField[Dynamic[Audiopath1], String, Enabled -> False], 
       FileNameSetter[Dynamic[Audiopath1], "Open", {".wav" -> {"*.wav"}}]}]}],
 (*Audio Record*)"Audio \Record", 
 Button["Record", Sound[SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]]]]
```

Comment: For import of sound files, try

    `?Import`

for exporting, try

    `?Export`

for recording, see this thread

    http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/is-it-possible-to-use-mathematica-to-record-sound-and-or-vision

Comment: Do you mean "I want to import sound from a file, record, and _export_ sound."?

Comment: If I click browse button, It will Import sound from file. 
If I click a record button, It will record sound and show the waveform

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Method -> "Queued"` to make the frontend to wait for the input from the sound recorder before finishing dynamic evaluation:

```
DynamicModule[{input = "ExampleData/rule30.wav", sound = ""},
 Panel@Column@{
    Row@{"Record: ", Button["Record", sound = SystemDialogInput@"RecordSound", 
       Method -> "Queued"], Button["Reset", sound = ""]},
    Row@{"Import: ",
         FileNameSetter[Dynamic[FindFile@input,
            (input = #; If[(input =!= $Failed \[Or] input =!= $Canceled) && 
            FileExistsQ@input, sound = Import@input]) &], "Open",
            {".wav" -> {"*.wav"}, ".*" -> {"*.*"}}],
         InputField[Dynamic[input], String, Enabled -> False]},
    Dynamic@sound
    }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]