# What SampleRate and SampleDepth does Mathematica use on output?

Tags: sound

The [`Play`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Play.html) function will happily accept arbitrary values for its [`SampleDepth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SampleDepth.html) and [`SampleRate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SampleRate.html) options.  For example, if I do:

```
Play[Sin[2 π 440 t], {t, 0, 1}, SampleDepth -> 240, SampleRate -> 480000]
```

… this will evaluate without a problem, and when I hit the play button, I will hear the sound.

But I know that my computer hardware is not capable of outputting sound at 240 bits and 480 kHz.

So what sample depth and rate am I actually hearing?  Does Mathematica use some standard rate for output (maybe 16 bits at 44.1 kHz)?  Does it use the maximum capability of my hardware (in my case, 24 bits at 48 kHz)?  Or something else?

Is there any way to query Mathematica for my system’s audio capabilities?

Comment: I don't know; [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20844/12) is marginally related and shows you how to query recording capabilities.  Some spelunking reveals that when *playing* sound, the `SampledSoundList` is wrapped in ``FEPrivate`EmitSound`` and sent to the front end for playing.  From there on everything's opaque to me.  I don't know any way to discover what the front end does with this data.

Comment: If you get no response here, try writing to Wolfram support and ask.  If they reply, let us know what they said (you can answer your own question).

Comment: IIRC, on Windows MM uses wave output, which then goes through SRC in the Windows audio stack to match whatever the output device is set to.