# Capturing microphone data

Tags: data-acquisition, input-devices

How to capture current microphone data, just like using the function `CurrentImage[]` for capturing image?

For example, this captures an image:

```
Dynamic [x = CurrentImage []; EdgeDetect [x, 3]]
```

But I don't want to use the function

```
SystemDialogInput ["RecordSound"]
```

since it requires user interaction, and I want recording to start programmatically.

---

EDIT: In his answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/is-it-possible-to-use-mathematica-to-record-sound-and-or-vision) (I saw it after I posted my question), @Szabolcs says that following works, but it is undocumented:

> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[5]] `` will list the available devices by number
> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[6, deviceNumber]] `` will list the available formats for the device
> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[1, deviceNumber, formatNumber]] `` will start recording.  It returns control
>     immediately.
> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[2]] `` will stop recording and return the duration.
> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[3]] `` will return the recorded sound (it's the "OK" button in the dialog)
> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[4]] `` will *probably* discard the recorded sound (it's the Cancel button)
> - `` FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`RecordSound[9, 0]] `` will return the current volume of the recorded sound, and is used for the progress
>     indicator in the dialog.

Is this changed or documented in latest Mathematica?

This is [current documentation on FrontEndExecute](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrontEndExecute.html).

Comment: No, it's still undocumented.  You could try using some external command line tool (sox?) to record the sound, then import the result to Mathematica.

Comment: I guess the [devices functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/UsingConnectedDevices.html) in V10 should allow you to do this, but you'd have to provide links to [device drivers](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingDeviceDrivers.html).

Comment: Voting to mark as duplicate  unless there's a reason the [linked Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4451/7167) isn't sufficient.