# How to produce timely spoken text?

Tags: sound

On my system (Mac OSX 10.10.4) the following code produces only the first utterance. The second one is produce when the user interacts in some way with the front end (mouseover, mouseclick). How can I avoid this strange behavior and produce timely speech?

```
Speak["you say goodbye"]
Speak["and i say hello"]
```

Comment: See these posts : [How to manipulate spoken text with Speak?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76942/how-to-manipulate-spoken-text-with-speak) and [How to export Speak output?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75797/how-to-export-speak-output/)

Comment: Thanks. I did see this material previously. It did not appear to answer my question.

Comment: What about : `Speak["you say goodbye [[slnc 1000]] and I say hello"]` ? Is this the kind of things you want to do ?

Comment: Or, maybe try : `Run["say " <> "you say goodbye"] ; Run["say " <> "and i say hello"]` (only works on OSX)

Comment: abwatson, I cannot reproduce the behavior you described in MMA 10.2 on Win7-64 bit. When executing those two expressions, the system generates speech for both even without any user interaction. It seems then that your problem may be system-dependent.

Comment: Here is another example. In this case only a single beep is produced.

Comment: This seems to be a widespread problem. It also occurs with Beep and EmitSound. If you put a pause between the two calls, it usually fixes the problem, but not always. It seems to relate to some call for external system   speech or sound resources.

Comment: Here is another example. 
In this case only a single beep is produced.
Beep[]
Beep[]

Comment: I can reproduce all your observations on OSX 10.9.5, with MMA 10.2 but I think it concerns previous versions also (OSX only). As you said in the comments, putting a `Pause` between two calls seem to be a workaround for `Beep` or `EmitSound`. In the case of  `Speak` the two workarounds i proposed in the comments work for me. I don't know if it can be considered as a bug, but it should be obviously be fixed. Maybe you should edit your post (and title) to include all these observations, so more people could test and comment ?

Comment: I had this with a bluetooth headphone. No problem with wired device.