# How to record a sound and play the reverse of that in Mathematica?

Tags: sound

How do I record a sound and then play its reversed version?

Comment: Do you want to Record it with _Mathematica_ or are you fine with importing the sound?

Comment: There are no hidden messages in Beatles records

Comment: importing is fine

Comment: [This post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/is-it-possible-to-use-mathematica-to-record-sound-and-or-vision?noredirect=1&lq=1) have discuss the first question about  how to record.

Comment: @Mikehoneychurch Actually there is at least one.  If the runout track on one side of Sgt Pepper vinyl is played backwards it says "Paul McCartney is dead" I have the LP and have done this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 11, *.wav files are now imported as `Audio[]` objects. Thus, using glS's example:

```
s = Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav"];
Audio[Reverse[AudioData[s]]];
```

[image: click to hear]

---

So that people who were hoping to hear actual backmasking would not be disappointed, let me give another example: the opening theme from the Disney animated series *[Gravity Falls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Falls)*. Using the last 5 seconds of the theme:

```
gf5 = Import["https://a.clyp.it/1mftdou4.mp3"];
```

As this is a stereo (two-channel) sound file, `Reverse[]` has to be mapped across the two channels:

```
Audio[Reverse /@ AudioData[gf5]];
```

[image: click to listen]

You should be hearing something like "three letters back" being whispered.

Comment: the link to the audio file is broken!

Comment: @glS, unfortunately Clyp seems to have changed its policies regarding anonymous uploads and the length of their validity. I'll ping you when I can find a more suitable host.

Answer (score 13):

Let's first try with a sound sample from MMA examples repository:

```
s = Import["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]
```

A `FullForm` of `s` reveals that this object has the structure `Sound[SampledSoundList[{listOfSounds},samplesRate]]`.
From this it looks like to play the sound in reverse we just need to `Reverse` listOfSounds, which we can do for example like this:

```
s /. SampledSoundList[{soundsList_}, r_] :> SampledSoundList[{Reverse@soundsList}, r]
```

Let's wrap this up in a function:

```
playInReverse[Sound[SampledSoundList[{soundsList_}, r_]]] := Sound[
   SampledSoundList[{Reverse@soundsList}, r]
   ];
playInReverse[Sound[SampledSoundList[{soundsLists__}, r_]]] := Sound[
   SampledSoundList[
    Reverse /@ {soundsLists},
    r
    ]
   ];
```

where I used a very specific pattern assignment because this method works only for that specific structure of a `Sound` object, and the second assignment rule is for tracks over more than one channel.

Here you can see how it works:

[image]

The exact same procedure works with sounds recorded from inside Mathematica.
See for example [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20844/27539) for some methods to record sound. A simple way is to use `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]`, which brings up a dialog to record the sound.
The generated object is exactly of the form mentioned above, so that you can use

```
playInReverse[SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]]
```

to record a sound and have it directly reversed.

Just for the heck of it, I tried this with a Beatles song (Yesterday) in mp3 format, and it works (no hidden messages though).

Comment: for fun try some of these.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backmasked_messages